# Continuity of the restriction of a function 3

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F$ be a compact of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $f$ a real valued function defined on a neighborhood of $F$, and set $$A=\{x\in F: f(x)=0\}.$$ Suppose that for all $y\in A$ we have$$\lim f(y)=0$$ as $y\to x$ form inside $F$.

1) Can we conclude that $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

2) Can we conclude that $A$ is closed in $F$?

Comment: Your "limit condition" is inexact. What do you mean exactly? 'as $y \to x$ from inside $F$' is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=(1,2), F=[0,3]$  and $f(x)=0$ for $x \in A$, $1$ for all other $x$. This shows that $A$ need not be closed either in $F$ or in $\mathbb R$.